# SQL - use offset/fetch with group by to divide a table in split and import a single split

Tags: sql, ssms, offset, azure-synapse

i got a table that i need to import, but the weight of the data is to high to be imported in just one operation. so i decided to split the table in 4 and import in pararel the 4 splits.
the muber of rows changes at every import.

So i created a varible that is 1/4 of the total number of rows with the filters i need to get the right number of rows:

```
declare @row_to_get int

set @row_to_get = (select
    *
from
    [AAA].[tablename]
where
    datepart(ss, [tempo]) = 0 
  and   
    datepart(mi, [tempo]) % 3 = 0
  and
    DateKey > @startDateKey_Extended)
/4
```

then i try like this:

```
select
     [Id]
    ,[Datekey]
    ,[tempo]
    ,max(coalesce([othercolumn], 1)) as [othercolumn] 
from
    [AAA].[tablename]
where
   datepart(ss, [tempo]) = 0 
   and  datepart(mi, [tempo]) % 3 = 0
   and  DateKey > @startDateKey_Extended
group by
     [Id]
    ,[Datekey]
    ,[tempo]
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @row_to_get ROWS ONLY
```

and for the second split:

```
select
     [Id]
    ,[Datekey]
    ,[tempo]
    ,max(coalesce([othercolumn], 1)) as [othercolumn] 
from
    [AAA].[tablename]
where
   datepart(ss, [tempo]) = 0 
   and  datepart(mi, [tempo]) % 3 = 0
   and  DateKey > @startDateKey_Extended
group by
     [Id]
    ,[Datekey]
    ,[tempo]
OFFSET @row_to_get ROWS FETCH NEXT @row_to_get*2 ROWS ONLY
```

and so on.

but i got that error: `Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'`

how can i try to rewrite that sintax in a smarter way?
it is mandatory that is linked to a parameter: number of rows that i need, not all the rows in the table
and that i keep the group by

Comment: Why `GROUP BY` when there are no aggregate functions involved? Are you just trying to do `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: Reading tip: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Comment: your first query doesn't seem to give back a number which you can divided, can you provide sample data  for your table

Comment: @jarlh 'cause i'm dumb and when i was editing my sintax to post the question i remove all the select statements and put * instead. see now for the edit

Answer (score 0):

Currently, **OFFSET/FETCH** clause is not supported in Azure Synapse.

However, there are some workarounds.

1. Use **TOP** clause to get rows from offset and fetch variables.

Example:

```
    Declare @fetchrows int = 2;
    Declare @offsetposition int = 2;

    SELECT *
    FROM (
       SELECT TOP (@fetchrows) *
       FROM
              (SELECT TOP(0+@fetchrows) *
                      FROM dbo.sampledata
                      ORDER BY id ASC
              ) AS a
       ORDER BY id DESC
        ) AS b
    ORDER BY id ASC


   SELECT *
   FROM (
       SELECT TOP (@fetchrows) *
       FROM
              (SELECT TOP((@offsetposition*1)+@fetchrows) *
                      FROM dbo.sampledata
                      ORDER BY id ASC
              ) AS a
       ORDER BY id DESC
        ) AS b
   ORDER BY id ASC
```

2. **ROW_NUMBER** window function to get the rows of row_number between offset and fetch variables.

Reference: [Paginating results in Synapse SQL](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics/paginating-results-in-synapse-sql/ba-p/1740735)